# What engine is behind Duolingo Forum?

Tags: forum

I am working on a project where building a community is an important step. A forum seems to be a good idea for this goal. I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so I've been thinking about Forum engines to use. I am not very knowledgeable in the area.

I've used and really liked [Duolingo](https://forum.duolingo.com/) forum. I don't think they built it all from scratch. I've tried to take a look at the website's source code in the search of any leads about what engine/service they're using, but haven't found any leads.

**Any idea what engine/software/tools they are using to run Duolingo's forum?**

Appreciatively,

EDIT:
I was asked to better outline my requirements in the comments. Here is my shot:

- The Forum engine would need as little of a set up as possible. We are developing an app, so we don't want to waste time developing a forum.
- The forum needs to be as user friendly as possible. We are targeting parents and teachers as the audience, not a community of geeks. Less is more.
- Common Forum features are a must: Users, profiles, posts. Niceties are not that important (e.g., tagging other users). We're looking for the minimum viable thing for building a large community of alpha/beta testers (and potentially active users), but the forum is not the main thing. This is why the Duolingo forum is potentially a good example of what we're looking for.

Comment: I think it is software recommendation question, although an uncommon one, but imho it is more ontopic than off.

Comment: Well, it strongly borderlines [Is software identification on-topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/818/185) It would be better if you could outline your requirements (see: [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)) The Duolingo Forum could be a reference, but cannot be the only "hint" to what you are looking for. Can you please **[edit]** your question accordingly, Jose?

Comment: Hi Izzy. I gave it a shot specifying the requirements. They are not too technical, it's more about user experience and specific features.

Comment: according to [builtwith.com](https://builtwith.com), there seems to be no recognised forum platform used on forum.duolingo.com. This would suggest it is hand-rolled from scratch.